# How to set SPRING MVC web application context as ROOT (/) on Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc

I have SPRING MVC web application (my.war). It deploys on Tomcat 6 server to `http://host/my/` folder. How can I change this to be accessible this web application in `http://host/` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `/ROOT` directory under `/webapps`. In default installation it holds bunch of exploded JSPs and `/WEB-INF` subdirectory that are accessible from main context.

Comment: I copied all files and dirs from /my to /ROOT, restarted server and I got Error404

Comment: ok I had to correct path and docRoot in server.xml to load spring class loader

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy your web application as ROOT.war

Have a look at this post which describes the whole topic pretty well:
 http://benhutchison.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/how-to-configure-tomcat-root-context/

Answer (score 0):

remove ROOT folder and make your app as ROOT.war
deploy it as ROOT folder