# Spring, Tomcat trying to set Context URL path in server.xml and it's not working

Tags: java, spring, url, tomcat, contextpath

I've been trying to figure out how to do this and as far as I can tell I am doing what the various resources I have found say to do. I have a Spring application called spring-hibernate-mysql that I want to be able to access at the path: `http://example.com/l/` rather than the way I currently have to at: `http://example.com/spring-hibernate-mysql/l/`.

My app name as it appears in eclipse is `spring-hibernate-mysql` and when I build it the war is called `spring-hibernate-mysql.war`

I have placed this code in my Tomcat's server.xml but it is not working: `<Context docBase="spring-hibernate-mysql" path="" reloadable="true" />`

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't this be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204383/how-to-set-spring-mvc-web-application-context-as-root-on-tomcat/5204395

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup this in your web.xml in filter mappings.

e.g.:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myapp</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/l/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: ah ok not sure why I wasn't able to find out that from searching, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you rename your war as l.war and then place l.war inside Tomcat's webapp directory then you will be able to use `http://mydomain.com/l/` to access your application.