# Ignore folder name in webapps for application URL

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, indexing

There is `myProject.war`

So, in order to run it on local Tomcat I should use following URL:

```
http://localhost:8099/myProject/index.html
```

The same problem is for my remote site- I should add name of folder,such as:

```
http://mySiteURL/myProject/index.html
```

web.xml content:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

how to do,that my site index page was accessible just by URL:
http://mySiteURL/

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set SPRING MVC web application context as ROOT (/) on Tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204383/how-to-set-spring-mvc-web-application-context-as-root-on-tomcat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to deploy as **ROOT.war**

Comment: it almost helped me,so for now i can access my site by "url/index.html", but just "url" redirects me to standard hoster page

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://java.sg/configure-jboss-as-context-root-to-your-struts-2-application/) is one way how i would do it for a Struts 2 application.